# How to check if a character is an extended ascii character in C?

Tags: c, ascii

Every time i do something similar to the condition below i get a Multicharacter warning.

```
    char str[] = "León";

    if(str[2] == 'ó') printf(true);
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't a thing. There's ASCII, and there's "not ASCII". That's like "extended facts".

Comment: Remove the `ó`. `printf(true);` does not make sense. Google wide characters

Comment: @boriaz50: I read that page and it's clear that there isn't _an_ extended ASCII, it's just a "sometimes criticized" term for some set of 8-bit character encoding schemes.

Comment: I don't find the term extended ASCII at all useful. My old Amstrad CPC464 had a different "extended ASCII" to the one linked above, and a clever way of redefining the characters! Why don't folk use the term UTF-8 and be done with it?

Comment: @Bathsheba because the internet started in the US. And because they needed to communicate between the west coast and the east coast we have figured from the start how to deal with timezones. But everything outside of ASCII was considered *exotic* and not worth bothering with. And so when the internet spread beyond the US, whoever needed characters outside of ASCII improvised on their own. That's why we have the cluster f**k that are the system codepages, or encodings like [JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_encoding), [EUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code) etc. [cont]...

Comment: ...[cont] And so Windows has a fixed size 2 bytes for UTF-16, although the encoding is truly variable length. And so C++ pretended for a long time that Unicode doesn't exist. And so up until today we don't have a standard, clean and complete way of working with UTF-8 on C++.

Comment: @bolov Incidentally, I was forced to adopt Rust as my primary systems language because I struggled to find a mature utf8/unicode library for C++. All of them seemed to be quite small and still being changed frequently. I'd be pretty interested in recommendations if anybody found a satisfactory one.

Comment: @Aaron3468 never worked with it, but I know that [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is the most complete and fairly wide used. Although I suspect it's not very easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the *encoding* on your platform is such that `'ó'` can fit into a `char`, `'ó'` is a multi-character constant. It seems to be the latter on your platform, judging by the message you get. The values of multi-character constants are *implementation defined*. In other words, the choice of numeric value is up to the implementation, with some constraints (e.g. it must be outside the `char` range on your platform).

Sadly in your case when you write `char str[] = "León";`, the third element will be converted to a `char`, using a *narrowing conversion*, or decomposed into more than one `char` and *concatenated* to the `char[]` array. So attempts to compare it to `'ó'` will be futile.

Comment: the narrowing conversion doesn't happen necessarily. I've checked with gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 and a UTF-8 encoded C source and got `strlen( str ) == 5`. Nevertheless the char comparison doesn't make any sense here either because `str[2]` contains the first byte of the UTF-8 sequence only.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: I'll take your word for it: I've amended the answer to include the apparent *concatenation* allowance. I'll check later today if the standards allow this. (Or answer yourself with a guaranteed upvote from me.)

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't. It's definitely what I've just experienced.

Comment: In the source file, "León" is a sequence of bytes that meet the requirements/restrictions of a literal string. It doesn't matter what bytes are between the quotes as long as they don't break the literal string rules, such as quote characters, linefeed characters, mal-formed escapes, etc. It seems that there are five bytes between the quotes and they work just fine as a literal string.

Comment: @TomBlodget That's implementation defined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, which source charsets are accepted is implementation-defined. Literal strings can be formed of the characters in the source character set except the double quotation mark ("), backslash (\), or newline character, which can be introduced with escapes. So, I don't see where an implementation-defined behavior rule would be involved.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `wchar_t` type, or a unicode library. `wchar_t` is infamous for having many gotchas and easy bugs to hit, but it is the best primitive type available to C++ compilers.

You need to use variants of everything that support `wchar_t`, such as `std::wcout` or `wprintf`.

EDIT: `wchar_t` has been replaced by `char16_t` and `char32_t`. The Unicode Standard 4.0 suggests their use whenever code must be portable between platforms, because `wchar_t` varies in size depending on platform (like `int` does).

I recommend finding a good unicode library to handle comparison between the many characters that are made of multiple codepoints!

The other option is to stick entirely to the native `char` type which is generally interpreted as some locale-specific ASCII.

Comment: The question is tagged in C not C++ though.

Comment: @Antti Haapala There is a lot of cross-transfer between C and C++ due to having shared compilers. C90 defined `wchar_t`. It seems to have been supplanted by the newer `char16_t` and `char32_t` types which are less ambiguous. They're present in both C and C++, just as the `wchar_t` type is.

Comment: Indeed, though `char16_t` and `char32_t` are less ambiguous only in size only, and the standard signals slight preference for them being in UTF-16 and UTF-32 by default. They're not very useful in standard C though, because the standard only supplies conversions from and to multibyte characters only; all the rest are left for the library authors to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the extended ASCII characters, use their octal value.

I am using the table http://www.asciitable.com/ and I guess the value you require is 162 (decimal) = 242. So use `str[] = "Le\242n"`;

And use the same in the comparison.

Comment: This is wrong, the OP is clearly using UTF-8, and not some crippled "Extended ASCII".

Comment: @Anti Haapala Depends on the usecase. OP is using UTF8 compatible characters, but the target platform may not support them. In the past I've had to use exactly this solution to interface with an lcd that interpreted bytes as Shift-JIS. This solution has the benefit that it allows direct comparison of any character supported by the target encoding. Please do not make assumptions without research.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII is a 7-bit character coding that numbers characters `0` ... `127`. An ASCII-compatible encoding preserves the meanings of these bytes. Any character encoded as `c < 0` or `c > 127` cannot be an ASCII character. These sometimes can be called by various confusing names such as "Extended ASCII" or alike.

In Unicode, the ASCII characters are still the characters 0 ... 127 of the Unicode codepoint range.

---

The problem is not as much that `ó` is an extended character, it is that your source file is actually in **UTF-8**, and therefore `ó` is encoded as *2 bytes*. `char` in C stands for the thing generally called as *byte* elsewhere.

C also supports *wide-character* strings, where each character is a UTF-16, UCS-2, UTF-32, or some other code point. There your `ó` would (most probably) be a single `wchar_t`.

Unfortunately you've opening a can of worms here, because the symbol `ó` can also be written in Unicode in 2 separate ways: It can be written as one code point `ó` or the letter `o` followed by the combining acute accent: `́`; both have the same semantic information, but they would consist of different bytes. And even if converted to `wchar_t` strings, these would still have different sequences. The C standard library doesn't handle the Unicode at all, except in C11, where there is some support for character literals explicitly in UTF-8. The C standard still doesn't present a portable way for converting UTF-8 encoded textual data to `wchar_t`; neither can it do normalizations such as `ó` to `o ́` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
if (sizeof("ó") > 2) ...
```

If this is just one `char` the length of your string is `2`, one for the character and one for the terminating `0`. Otherwise if it doesn't fit the compiler will allocate a longer sequence.

Answer (score 0):

When you give your source file to the compiler you have to tell which character encoding you used with your source editor (source charset). My guess that it is UTF-8, which encodes ó as 0xC3 0xB3. This seems to be going right.

But 'ó' then becomes an integer with a value outside your `char` range (see your `<limits.h>`). Therefore the warning on the `==` between them.

BTW—there is some meaning in "Extended ASCII" but not much. An "Extended ASCII" character set must encode each of its codepoints in one byte. So, UTF-8 is not an encoding for one of the many "Extended ASCII" character sets.