# how can i compare characters from the Extended ASCII Codes that are stored in a character array?

Tags: c, extended-ascii

I'm using the ASCII code 219 to print out "█" in a character array. however I would like to check the value of that cell later on in the program using a if statment.
this is what i currently have to try to check the value: `if(gameboard[playery][playerx] == 219){}`. however is vs code it will give a message stating that the comparison is allways faulse due to range limitations for the data type.
is there a diffrent way of doing this?

i've tried single and double quotes aswell as using the box as plan text in the program but none of that works. i also tried using the octal value from [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562185/22909800) in a diffrent post however the message still appered.

Comment: Your default char is likely signed so it has values from -128 to 127. The easiest way out is probably a cast like `(char)219`. Extra explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char

Comment: The first thing to learn is that there is no such thing as "extended ASCII".

Comment: 219 is _not_ an ASCII code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about whether the char is signed or not, but I think that @teapost418 is correct that you just have to type cast 219 as a char:

```
if(gameboard[playery][playerx] == (char) 219){}
```

I think that otherwise 219 would be interpreted as an int.

Comment: Or better, just declare a constant `static const char block = 219;` so that it has a name as well as the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code 219 as ASCII is 7-bit.

The are various [extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) codings with a value of 219.

---

`<string.h>` compare routines like `strcmp()` examine the several characters as if they were `unsigned char` even when `char` is *signed*.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).  C23dr § 7.26.1 4

`fgetc()` reads a *character* and returns, as an `int`, an `unsigned char` value or `EOF`.

I recommend to compare individual `char` in the same fashion to provide consistent functionality when *strings* are used.

```
// if(gameboard[playery][playerx] == 219){}
if((unsigned char)gameboard[playery][playerx] == 219){}
```

... or perhaps make `gameboard[][]` an array of `unsigned char`.  Yet need to see overall code to fully endorse this approach.